# Find all paths between two nodes using BFS

Tags: java

My question is a little bit strange, but I have this project for school and I need to find all paths between 2 nodes and save them in a list. The strange part is that I have to traverse the graph in a BFS order. I know that there are other algorithms that could be used more eficientlly for my problem but I have to use BFS. I represented the graph as an adjancy matrix, it is weighed and undirected. Can anyone help me with some ideas please.

```
public class A {
    private static int[][] adjacency = new int [5][5];
    static int n = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                adjacency[i][j] = 0;    
        adjacency[0][1] = 2;
        adjacency[0][3] = 1;
        adjacency[1][0] = 2;
        adjacency[1][2] = 5;
        adjacency[2][1] = 5;
        adjacency[2][3] = 1;
        adjacency[2][4] = 2;
        adjacency[3][0] = 1;
        adjacency[3][2] = 1;
        adjacency[4][2] = 2;

        List<Queue<Integer>> paths = findPath(0,2,adjacency);
        System.out.println(paths);
    }

    public static List<Integer> getNeighbors(int node, int[][] a) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            if (a[node][i] != 0)
                list.add(i);
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Queue<Integer>> findPath(int start, int end, int[][] a) {
        List<Queue<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();
        Queue<Integer> toVisit = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> visited = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        toVisit.add(start);
        while(!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
              int node = toVisit.remove();
              visited.add(node);
              List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              neighbors = getNeighbors(node,a);
        }
          return paths;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code, a sample of the input, and the desired output.

Comment: The main difference between a Breath First Search and a Depth First Search is that a BFS uses a Queue, where a DFS uses a Stack (and usually remembers which nodes it's visited to avoid getting trapped in loops)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GraphStructure {
private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map = new HashMap();

public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
        map.put(node1, adjacent);
    }
    adjacent.add(node2);
}

public void addTwoWayVertex(String node1, String node2) {
    addEdge(node1, node2);
    addEdge(node2, node1);
}

public boolean isConnected(String node1, String node2) {
    Set adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return adjacent.contains(node2);
}

public LinkedList<String> adjacentNodes(String last) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(last);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return new LinkedList();
    }
    return new LinkedList<String>(adjacent);
}
}

public class BFSImplementation{

public static int count;
public static Hashtable hash; 
private static final String START = "B";
private static final String END = "E";

public BFSImplementation() {
     hash=new Hashtable();
     count=0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    GraphStructure graph = new GraphStructure();

    graph.addEdge("A", "B");

    graph.addEdge("A", "C");

    graph.addEdge("B", "A");

    graph.addEdge("B", "D");

    graph.addEdge("B", "E"); // this is the only one-way connection

    graph.addEdge("B", "F");

    graph.addEdge("C", "A");

    graph.addEdge("C", "E");

    graph.addEdge("C", "F");

    graph.addEdge("D", "B");

    graph.addEdge("E", "C");

    graph.addEdge("E", "F");

    graph.addEdge("F", "B");

    graph.addEdge("F", "C");

    graph.addEdge("F", "E");

    LinkedList<String> visited = new LinkedList();
    visited.add(START);
    new BFSImplementation().breadthFirst(graph, visited);
   }      
   public static  void breadthFirst(GraphStructure graph, LinkedList<String> visited) {
    LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());

    for (String node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node.equals(END)) {
            count++;
            visited.add(node);
            printPath(count,visited);
            visited.removeLast();
            break;
        }
    }
    // in breadth-first, recursion needs to come after visiting adjacent nodes
    for (String node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node) || node.equals(END)) {
            continue;
        }
        visited.addLast(node);
        breadthFirst(graph, visited);
        visited.removeLast();
    }
    }
    public static  void printPath(int count,LinkedList<String> visited) {       
    String temp="";
    for (String node : visited) {
        temp=temp+node+",";            
       // System.out.print(node);
       // System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Available Path  "+count+": : : :"+ temp);     
    hash.put(count,temp);
    //System.out.println("exp = " + hash.toString());       
    }
    }
```